# Codeignitor Routing not working in subfolder

Tags: codeigniter, routes

i have created a project in codeigniter, in which i am using routing as follows,

```
$route['dashboard'] = 'controllerName/dashboard';
```

which runs fine of my pc. My client provided me domain `www.abc.com` on which another project is already running. He asked me to create subfolder on domain like `www.abc.com/newFolder` and hosted new project inside the folder. After doing so unfortunately all the rules for routing are not working.

After searching on google i tried some solution but they didnt work. What i am expecting is that when i hit `www.abc.com/newFolder/dashboard` it should redirect to my `function` `dashboard` inside `controller`.

what i tired is...

```
$route['dashboard'] = 'newFolder/controllerName/dashboard';
```

but no luck. will anybody put me on right direction what mistake i am making. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the base url to the sub folder ?

Comment: change your base_url as "www.abc.com/newFolder" in config.php and remove it from 'newFolder/controllerName/dashboard';